# Как по нажатию кнопки вставить значение из инпута в редактируемую li?

Tags: reactjs

Нужно вывести элементы массива в виде списка ul. Под списком реализовать инпут для редактирования пунктов списка. В конце каждой li стоит кнопка, по нажатию на которую начинает редактироваться эта li.

```
    function App() {
  let [notes, setNotes] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  let [editNum, setEditNum] = useState(null);
  let [forBtn, setForBtn] = useState("");
  let copyNotes = notes.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <>
        <li key={index} onClick={()=>{setEditNum(index)}}>{item} </li>
        <button onClick={() => {setNotes(forBtn)}}>press</button>
      </>
    );
  });

  function handlerChange(e) {
    setForBtn([...notes.slice(0, editNum), e.target.value, ...notes.slice(editNum + 1)]);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <ul>{copyNotes}</ul>
      <input value={editNum ? notes[editNum] : ""} onChange={handlerChange} />
    </>
  );
}
```

(Новичок - самоучка) : Не могу понять , почему не работает привязка value инпута к переменной , и по нажатию на кнопку данные из переменной передать в стейт. Передает один символ , а не все что есть в инпуте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если можно есть другой подход:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

function App() {

  let [notes, setNotes] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  let [value, setValue] = useState()
  // --
  function handlerClickButton(index) {
    if(value!=='') {
      setNotes(notes => {
        notes[index] = value
        return notes
      })
      setValue('')
    }
  }
  // --
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {
          notes.map((item, index) => (
              <>
                <li key={index} onClick={()=>{setEditNum(index)}}>{item} </li>
                <button onClick={() => handlerClickButton(index)}>press</button>
              </>
            ))
        }
      </ul>
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    </>
  )

}
```